# Find a CFG for $a^{2n}b^na^k$ where $n,k \ge 0$

Tags: context-free-grammar

I need to provide a CFG for $L=\{a^{2n}\cdot b^n \cdot a^k | n,k \ge 0\}$ .So I am perplexed on how to account for $a^k$ as $S -> aaSb | \epsilon$ gives me $a^{2n}b^n$ but if I do anything like $S -> aaSbT$ the I start getting garbage like,
$aaaaSbTbT$.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you learning context-free grammar in a math course or by a math book? Where did you find the problem?

Comment: @Apass.Jack it's from archives of mathematical tripos examination.

Comment: Ah, the Mathematical Tripos. Nowadays questions about formal grammar are better raised on [cs.se].